# OOM Netty with broken or slow clients

Tags: netty

I have a Netty Server (3.6.2) that generates some data and broadcast to subscribed clients. Sometimes some clients seem to don't get the data because the client is broken or the network resources are in poor condition. In this case the server fills the Channel write queue and keeps generating events and eventually this could lead to an OutOfMemoryError.

One solution could be check if the channel isWritable() before writing and don't write in negative case (anyway I have to store this messages or I'll lose them). But I'd rather disconnect clients that are not flushing the write buffer in some time or at the pace I'm generating the broadcast events.

How could I do that? How could implement this write buffer is not being flushed "timeout"? Should I close clients if isWritable is false?

I'd really appreciate any ideas.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah you could close the connection if Channel.isWritable() returns false.

Comment: Isn't it a bit drastic? In a Websocket connection maybe a client is just slow temporary and can recover pace. Isn't there some kind of timeout mechanism to implement in the handler like "if this client is not writable for more than x period, disconnect it?". I want to avoid the OOM but I wouldn't want to have a lot of clients loosing messages just because there is a temporary network problem.

Comment: WriteTimeoutHandler could be used to specify the maximum time allowed to write any single buffer. It'll throw an exception if the time is exceeded. This would achieve your goal but you still need to stop writing if channel.isWritable returns false to prevent OOM before the write timeout occurs. Alternatively, you could size the write buffer to the level of the maximum backlog you can sustain. Norman's answer would then be valid because channel.isWritable() == false would occur at the point at which the backlog is consider to be too great.